# Jquery twitter follow doesnt work after submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter

I've made this jquery code that should output a text message and submit a form after clicking the twitter follow button.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
twttr.events.bind('follow', function(e) {
$('.like-button1').text('Thanks!');
$('.form1').submit();     
    });
});
</script>
```

After click the follow button the text appears on the select div and form1 is submitted... but the follow button is not followed later refresh.... if i remove this part of code:

```
$('.like-button1').text('Thanks!');
$('.form1').submit();
```

it works and im followed but the form isnt submitted and thetext doesnt appears...

whats wrong?

Comment: try putting `e.preventDefault()` at the beginning of your `follow` func

Comment: Like this? <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
twttr.events.bind('follow', function(e) { e.preventDefault()
$('.like-button1').text('Thanks!');
$('.form1').submit();     
    });
});
</script>

Comment: doesnt works :( after click the follow button the text doesnt appears and the form werent submitted